# Cannot access secondary GPU

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

After turning on computer and login I cant use optirun.

```
$ optirun glxheads
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

But if I logout and login again everything works ok.
My hardware: MSI GP60, NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M].
Optirun config:

```
[bumblebeed]
VirtualDisplay=:8
KeepUnusedXServer=false
ServerGroup=bumblebee
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
NoEcoModeOverride=false
Driver=nvidia
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

[optirun]
Bridge=auto
VGLTransport=proxy
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
AllowFallbackToIGC=false



[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow NVidia driver is not loaded. After:

```
modprobe nvidia_352
```

command everything works normal.
Second solution is logout and login again.